# Data was not store in table using webservice. Any server cache memory where data may be in queue?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I created a webservice using php. This webservice is able to insert data in mysql table. In Android, I am passing data using GET method and this webservice get data and store in db.

I tested and it is working fine. But due to some reason, device **Mi 3** was not able to store data. and i did not data in table. I have not access this device now. Is there any cache store or memory store in server side where i can see data which was not store in table using webservice.

I know that is not good question. But i having that issue and want to see any possibility .

Comment: There is no such cache. I am afraid we cannot help without more details: your code, the relevant lines from the http servers access and error log files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to perform logging to a file of the whole request you receive to debug. Something like this perhaps.

```
file_put_contents('logfile.txt', print_r($_REQUEST, true));
file_put_contents('logfile.txt', print_r($_GET, true));
file_put_contents('logfile.txt', print_r($_POST, true));
```